# Extracting images from contours

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to figure out how to make a script that cuts out images from a sheet of images. I can't understand what to do after I get the contours of the images. My train of thought is to load a sheet, convert it to grayscale, find the contours, use them to cut out the images from the original colored image and save them individually.

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
from PIL import Image
from skimage import measure

# Inicialization
spritesToFind = argv[1]
spriteSize = argv[2]
sheet = Image.open(argv[3])

# To grayscale, so contour finding is easy
grayscale = sheet.convert('L')

# Let numpy do the heavy lifting for converting pixels to black or white
data = np.asarray(grayscale).copy()

# Find the contours we need
contours = measure.find_contours(data, 0.8)

# Now we put it back in PIL land

sprite = Image.fromarray(data)
sprite.save(str(spritesToFind), "PNG")
```

Comment: The answer will depend on what the sheet of images looks like.  You might be able to use find_contours, but you might need something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to cut out the smallest rectangle containing the contour you can use the (x,y) coordinates in the contour to create a bounding box going from (min(x), min(y)) to (max(x),max(y)).

If you want to zero out everything not inside a contour, you should look into how you can determine if a point is within a polygon, and then zero out everypoint point that is not inside the contour.

Comment: I want to cutout the smallest rectangle containing a contours, there are lots of contours. I don't understand how these things really work I am afraid. Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

Where `contours` is a list of countours found using `measure.find_contours`, and `x` is your image.  This shows how to do both a rectangle bounding box extract `image_patch` and how to extract *just* the pixels that are part of the polygon `new_image`:

```
from matplotlib import path

contour = contours[0]
path = path.Path(contour)

top = min(contour[:,0])
bottom = max(contour[:,0])
left = min(contour[:,1])
right = max(contour[:,1])

new_image = np.zeros([bottom-top,right-left])

for xr in range(new_image.shape[0]):
    for yr in range(new_image.shape[1]):        
        if(path.contains_point([top+xr,left+yr])):
            new_image[xr, yr] = x[top+xr, left+yr]


image_patch = x[top:bottom,left:right]

plt.imshow(image_patch)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(new_image)
plt.show()
```